# How to show the program output from the terminal and show the output using tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

Can the output of the speech recognition result be displayed in the window of  GUI using tkinter?

```
class panggil:
    def __init__(self):
        root = Toplevel()
        root.title("Speaker Recognition(Train)")

        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Speak Anything :")
            audio = r.listen(source)
            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                print("You said : {}".format(text))
            except:
                print("Sorry could not recognize your voice")

        root.mainloop()
```

Programs that have been executed don't display errors but don't show any output. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a `Text` box to show the result.  Also better to use a `Button` to trigger the recognition.  Below is a simple example based on your code:

```
from tkinter import *
import speech_recognition as sr

class panggil(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Speaker Recognition (Train)")
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # text box to show message and speech recognition result
        self.output = Text(self, width=40, height=20)
        self.output.pack()
        # button to start the speech recognition
        self.start_btn = Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_recognize)
        self.start_btn.pack()

    def say(self, msg):
        self.output.insert(END, f"{msg}\n")
        self.output.see(END)
        self.output.update()

    def start_recognize(self):
        self.start_btn.config(state=DISABLED)
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            self.say("Speak something ...")
            audio = r.listen(source, timeout=5, phrase_time_limit=2) # better specify timeouts (in case no sound is detected for certain period)
            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                self.say(f"You said: {text}")
            except:
                self.say("Sorry could not recognize your voice!")
        self.start_btn.config(state=NORMAL)

panggil().mainloop()
```